# Vaadin application gets hanged

Tags: javascript, java, charts, highcharts, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin for development of web applications. I am using Vaadin charts in my application. So when I go to chart window the entire application is getting hanged. Following is the error given in browser console:

[Highcharts Error #16](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16)

> Highcharts already defined in the page
>
> This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page, 
>   so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart 
>   constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock, 
>   so if you are running Chart and StockChart in combination, 
>   you only need to load the highstock.js file.

Also when I check my Tomcat Log I get following notification:

---

> LICENSE WARNING
>
> Vaadin Charts is a commercial product. After 30 days of evaluation use,
>   you must either acquire a license or stop using it. More information about
>   Commercial Vaadin Add-on License is available at
>   https://vaadin.com/license/cval-2.0.
>
> You may obtain a valid license by subscribing to Vaadin Pro Account at
>   https://vaadin.com/pro or by purchasing a perpetual license at
>   https://vaadin.com/directory.
>
> A valid license key is your perpetual license key purchased from Vaadin
>   Directory or alternatively the email address you use to login to an active
>   Vaadin Pro Account.
>
> Register your copy of Vaadin Charts by creating a file named
>   .vaadin.charts.developer.license containing the license key in your home 
>   directory or by setting the vaadin.charts.developer.license=license_key
>   system property to disable this message. Thank you.

---

Is this a license related problem? Is there any problem related with highcharts 16? I have spent a lot of time for this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code as it's only guessing without seeing anything.

Comment: As I see vaadin charts are based on highcharts, so includes highcharts.js. In case when yoo try to load highcharts.js and vaadin then you receive errors, because highcharts are multiple time. In other words, remove reference to highcharts.js.